# My last name is not the same on ticket as on passport; rest of details are same

Tags: air-travel, tickets, passports, paperwork

I'm traveling from JED Saudi Arabia to Singapore by Saudi airlines. My last name doesn't match the passport. But all other details are same, e.g. passport no., DOB, etc.

Comment: How big is the difference?  Completely different. or just a different spelling?

Comment: Seems like the best thing would be to call the airline and ask to have it corrected.  The sooner you do this the better; some airlines charge fees for any changes made after a certain period of time.

Comment: @NateEldredge totally true, some airlines like Saudi airlines have strict rules when it comes to change names. So the sooner the much better.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, to book for international flights you have to match the name in the booking with the name in the passport. How did you manage to get a different name? Anyway, the airline check-in agent will check the passport before printing the boarding pass. If the name does not match the agent might refuse you. There is a strict rules regarding this. Also, the passport control officers in Saudi Arabia will check the name in the boarding pass and make sure it matches the one in the passport.

Anyway, if the difference is just some letters then there will be no problem ([or if the name is reversed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16644/am-i-going-to-have-trouble-flying-with-a-reversed-name-on-the-ticket)). One thing to mention here, Arabs use three parts name or four parts name `first, middle, [middle 2], last`, if the name shown in the ticket is `first+middle[2]` or `first+last` or `last+middle` then most likely it will be ok.

If the name is totally different than the one in passport then that is a problem, just visit any ticketing office to fix it.

Comment: `First Middle Last Father's First Fathers's Middle Father's Last` is the official name on Saudi (and some other GCC country) official documents. On a reservation though, only the travellers `Last/FirstMiddle` is used; and if these are switched, then its generally allowed (personal experience).