# Last name on ticket different from ID

Tags: air-travel, tickets

This August I booked a plane ticket for my boyfriend thinking that the name I put was the correct one. I just found out that the last name on his state ID is not the same as his name on the ticket. Its a different last name completely he is adopted and apparently his last name wasn't legally changed to his adopted parents.

Is this going to be a problem? His flight is in 3 weeks. I bought it through Expedia and he is flying with Delta.

**EDIT:** This flight is domestic within the United States

Comment: Is this a domestic flight, as that may change the answer. You're best bet is to contact Delta directly and explain. This is similar to this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22088/my-last-name-is-not-the-same-on-ticket-as-on-passport-rest-of-details-are-same?rq=1 (although the answer may be different for a domestic flight so I'm not marking it as duplicate).

Comment: Yes, this flight is domestic Tucson to Atlanta

Comment: Any proof of relationship between those names will most likely help getting on board anyway. Did you only buy tickets or did you check in yet? If you didn't check in yet, make sure you put the correct name during check in and most likely everything should be fine. This happens all the time. Do contact Delta though!

Comment: I'm not aware that you can switch names during check in - at least its not possible on any domestic flights I've flown. You typically scan your ID (or punch it your reservation number) and then the kiosk asks you the requisite questions and prints the boarding pass.

Comment: I was speaking about online check in. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: What would be good proof to show for his names?

Answer (score 2):

If your boyfriend has any [TSA accepted ID](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) that has the name as listed on the reservation, he can use that.

Barring that, I'm afraid you may be charged a fee by Delta to change the name on the ticket; as you cannot fly if the name doesn't match that on the ID you are using to identify yourself.

There are some exceptions (like if the first/last name is switched - a common issue); but in your case its a completely different name.

Its like saying Burhan Khalid wants to travel on a ticket issued to Burhan Jones.