# Two letters of first name are swapped, can I still fly with Turkish Airlines?

Tags: tickets, airports, turkish-airlines

I have already seen [some other such questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16644/am-i-going-to-have-trouble-flying-with-a-reversed-name-on-the-ticket?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but in this case, I am hoping to know if somebody has this experience with long-haul Turkish Airlines flights (Munich to Tokyo via Istanbul).

When booking the ticket, I accidentally swapped two letters of my wife's first name (e.g. instead of `Abcd Ijkl`, the name on the ticket is `Acbd Ijkl`).

We called to Turkish Airlines and they said that they cannot change the name. **They said that they have passed the information to the airport but they cannot guarantee if my wife can fly.**

Since this is return ticket so, I am not sure if we may have a problem on the return flight in Japan.
Please let me know if anyone has such experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as primarily opinion based. We cannot predict the future in such situations.

Comment: @JonathanReez: This question is asking to share the experience of other people (who have been in similar situation with Turkish Airlines). I guess that on a traveling Q&A platform, people can only share their experiences and nobody is expecting (and nobody can) to predict the future. Had it been a programming/technology based question, I wouldn't have asked such question.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any answer on the internet till date who had mentioned the solution to this issue (with Turkish Airlines) so, I am sharing my solution. There are two possible solutions:

1. Don't do anything and just go to the airport and try your luck. Turkish Airlines told me that there should not be any problem but they cannot guarantee.
2. I called Turkish Airlines and they told me to fill out the ***feedback form*** with all the information.

   - After 2 days, I received an email stating that your name change is not possible but please send us the copy of your passport for further investigation.
   - I sent the copy of passport and after 2 days, I got a call from customer care from Turkey and he told me that though the name change is not possible but in good faith, they are providing me one solution to this problem.
   - He suggested canceling the current ticket (**which was non-refundable and booked via the third party**) and receive a full refund via an approval code directly from Turkish Airlines (***without involving third-party at all***) and book a new ticket with the current price.
   - Since the difference between the refund and the new ticket price was 44€ only, so I immediately accepted the offer.
   - I booked the new ticket via the same telephone call itself and received my new ticket in few minutes. The refund approval code I received on the following day.

> Now to get the Refund, I have to visit the Turkish Airlines Sales
>   Office, which is at Munich Airport in my case.

**PS:** I don't think that it was really necessary for Turkish Airlines  to help me since it was all my mistake but I am very thankful to them for helping out so quickly.