# Can I travel with just my first name on ticket?

Tags: turkish-airlines

I recently booked a return ticket from Egypt, I made an error where I entered my Middle name in the surname textbox, I only realised this after completing the booking. I have contacted Turkish Airline who are flat out not willing to change the name or help in any shape or form. Can I still fly as my first name and Middle name  on my passport but under the first name section, and the surname is not included in the ticket but obviously it is on my passport.

Comment: What did Turkish Airlines say about allowing you to board? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116296/two-letters-of-first-name-are-swapped-can-i-still-fly-with-turkish-airlines

Comment: Putting on hold until clarified