# How to book a United Airlines ticket if my passport doesn't have a last name?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, united-airlines

What should I put in the "LastName" section while booking a flight with United Airlines, when my Passport only has "FirstName".
Can I use my "FirstName" in both the places?

Comment: Like other Stacks, we expect users to report what research they've already done to answer their own questions. So: have you asked this question of United Airlines?

Comment: There are similar questions: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16644/am-i-going-to-have-trouble-flying-with-a-reversed-name-on-the-ticket

Comment: Is the lack of a last name in your passport an error (in other words, do you have both a first name and a last name and the people who made your passport screwed up)? If so, I highly recommend you get your passport corrected first, or it's likely to cause a lot of confusion and problems for you in the future.

Comment: Indian passport can be updated within a week in most cases so get it rectified.

Answer (score 6):

For US Visa puporses, it looks like you need to use your single name as "last name" and FNU as first name. FNU means "first name unknow". See https://in.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/ FAQ section. It's likely that United will adopt the same process since they need to communicate booking data and Visa data to US immigration authorities. However, you should call and ask them to confirm.

However, it's likely that you will run into a lot of issues and if possible you should try to get your Indian passport fixed before you travel. https://redbus2us.com/surname-blank-in-passport-first-name-as-fnu-in-us-visa-issues-solution/

Comment: "However, you should call and ask them to confirm." => can we call on behalf of OP to create a canonical answer?

Comment: Since this will vary by country and airline, I think the "canonical" answer here is "fix your passport". Even if you get the ticket booked, you'll run into trouble with other reservations, Covid test reports, travel registrations, car rentals, etc.

Comment: Not sure why you all assume that there is a global agreement that all people _have_ last names. Each country can make their rules as they like, and maybe he has legally only a first name in his country? I have work colleagues in that situation, so it exists.

Comment: Sure, it does exist and it's not illegal. However, you can save yourself or lot of administrative trouble and extra paperwork if you get a first & last name.

Comment: @Hilmar It's a bit rude to tell someone to "fix" their name to confirm to some arbitrary foreign standard, no?

Comment: Sorry, I was just quoting: https://redbus2us.com/surname-blank-in-passport-first-name-as-fnu-in-us-visa-issues-solution/ There is no judgement intended. Of course you are free to keep a single name (if your legislation allows it), but it's going to create a lot of extra paperwork, problems, and hiccups when traveling